# Ludwig Boltzmann: life and work

Tags: physics, biographical-details, book-recommendation, physicists, boltzmann

Could you suggest a good biographic book about the life and work of the physicist Ludwig Boltzmann?

Comment: You can try with: Carlo Cercignani, [Ludwig Boltzmann: the man who trusted atoms](https://books.google.it/books?id=vMVvJKqZJ_oC&printsec=frontcover) (1998).

Comment: cf. [his _Dictionary of Scientific Biography_ entry](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Ludwig_Boltzmann.aspx#1)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I didn't know that book was in English, too. thanks

Comment: @Geremia, actually I was looking for an extensive biography (like those by [Walter Isaacson](http://www.amazon.com/Walter-Isaacson/e/B000APFLB8)). Anyway thank you for your kind suggestion.

Comment: @mrnld I provided that mainly for the "secondary literature" bibliography at the end.